# de coordenadas a geohash

Tags: python, python-3.7, geolocalización

estoy trabajando en un codigo que tome mi latitud y longitud de las columnas de un archivo excel y que me pueda añadir una columna con el geohash calculado en ese mismo archivo.

Actualmente, tengo el codigo que me trae lat y long de un archivo y me lo calcula en otro archivo diferente. Me podrian ayudar para que todo lo haga en un mismo archivo?

```
import pygeohash as pgh
import xlwt  
import xlrd  
import pygeohash  
from xlutils.copy import copy
hang=0
lie=0

archivo = "FILE1.xls"
myWorkbook = xlrd.open_workbook(archivo)
mySheets = myWorkbook.sheets()
table=myWorkbook.sheets()[0] 
mySheets_rows=table.nrows
print(f"El archivo tiene: {mySheets_rows}")
 
mySheet = mySheets[0]  
 #table.cell(rowx, colx)



# myWorkbook2 = xlwt.Workbook() 
# mySheet2 = myWorkbook2.add_sheet('Geohash') 
archivo2 = 'FILE2.xls'
book2 = xlrd.open_workbook(archivo2)
r_sheet = book2.sheet_by_index(1)
wb = copy(book2)
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(1)

while hang<mySheets_rows: 
     myRowValues = mySheet.row_values(hang)  
    
     geogps = pgh.encode(float(myRowValues[1]), float(myRowValues[2]), precision=12) 
     for i in range(len(myRowValues)):
         w_sheet.write(hang, lie, myRowValues[i])
         lie+=1
     w_sheet.write(hang, lie, geogps)

     i=0
     lie=0
     hang+=1

wb.save('FILE2.xls')
```

Comment: si estas importando pandas, por que no lo utilizas?

Comment: Faltó que nos indiques cuál es el problema con tu código. :)

Comment: La idea es poder trabajar en un mismo archivo. que tome mi latitud y longitud de las columnas de un archivo excel y que me pueda añadir una columna con el geohash calculado en ese mismo archivo.

Comment: Ese codigo lo hace con dos archivos

Comment: La vida con pandas es muy sencilla, puedes hacer todo de forma muy simplificada :D

Comment: Me podrias indicar por medio de pandas?

Comment: si, pero dame un tiempo, no se nada de xlrd y tendría que pasar todo a pandas. Podrías poner el contenido del archivo 1??

Comment: el archivo 1 solo tiene un numero identificador de cliente, otra columan de lat y otra de long. Nada más

Comment: Es preferible que lo pongas, me ayudaría mucho :D